# Dynamic html form generation in MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, express

I've just started learning on MEAN stack and need to generate dynamic forms on the fly.

The requirement is to import document (excel/csv/xml/xls etc..) and generate dynamic forms using it so a user can update their data and again export it into the respective file.

So to accomplish this I'm converting documents to JSON format and storing JSON data into the MongoDB database.

Ex: Consider this `xlsx` data:

```
ID  Name       dob        Gender
1   user1      7-Dec-87   m
2   user2      8-Dec-87   f
3   user3      9-Dec-87   f
3   user4      4-Dec-87   m
```

And I'm converting this using `xlsx-to-json` module to JSON format and storing it into Mongodb.

```
app.post('/myapp', function (req, res) {

    //console.log("===========" + req.file.path);

    converter({
        input: req.file.path,
        output: "output.json"
    }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log(result);
            db.collection('test').insert(result, function (err, doc) {
                console.log(err);
                res.json(doc);
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Here I'm fetching above data from `Mongodb & express.js`

```
app.get('/myapp', function (req, res) {
    db.collection('test').find(function (err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
        res.json(docs);
    });
});

app.get('/birthdaylist/:id', function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    db.collection('test').findOne({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, function (err, doc) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
        res.json(doc);
    });
});
```

and here's the `JSON` output:

```
[ 
  { dob: '7-Dec-87', ID: '1', Name: 'user1' },
  { dob: '8-Dec-87', ID: '2', Name: 'user2' },
  { dob: '9-Dec-87', ID: '3', Name: 'user3' },
  { dob: '4-Dec-87', ID: '4', Name: 'user4' } 
]
```

So, I've few queries:

- Is this the correct approach I'm doing to generate dynamic form from xlsx/csv..etc ? If yes, then how can I generate dynamic form from above JSON.
- While exploring on google I've found mongodb generates  form automatically (https://github.com/GothAck/forms-mongoose)
  So will it help because there may be chance of huge data on excel files.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The above code looks fine for conversion, especially considering your output looks good.  Without an attempt at the front end code, SO can't help you much.  The github link you include is for Mongoose so unless you're using mongoose, it's not going to help you much.

Comment: And just as a small note on MongoDB, you're not actually storing JSON in Mongo, but [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/).

Comment: @metame: Thanks for replying. I tried moogose but its requires proper attributes in JSON format. In my case JSON is generating from excel file so how can I tackle that issue?

Comment: @metame: Ohh so its BSON.. Actually I'm using `mongojs` nodes module for inserting data

Comment: That sounds like another question that is a lot more clearer.  I would recommend posting that as a separate question or editing your question (and title) to ask that instead.  The way your current question is stated, a proper answer would require someone to write a bunch of code for you.

Comment: @metame: I don't want bunch of code. In fact just need some help/guide generate dynamic html from above JSON.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105394/discussion-between-mark-and-metame).

Answer (score 4):

Do you actually need to analyze an arbitrary spreadsheet and dynamically extract the schema, or do you know the schema ahead of time?  If you know the schema, then the Mongoose form generating example is straightforward.  But make sure that is actually a requirement because it is tough.

You are never going to be 100% because spreadsheets are created by users and users do weird things.  But you can make something that works most of the time.

You need something that takes a JSON object and extracts the schema and puts that in a Mongoose schema format.

So you want to add an interesting module to Mongoose schema.  I searched `node-modules.com` and this came up: https://github.com/Nijikokun/generate-schema

Comment: Yes you are right spreadsheets are created by users and they do weird things that why I want to convert it into the JSON format

Comment: Right, so see the rest of the answer.  Can you see if the generate-schema or another one from node-modules.com will work to get the schema from the JSON?

Comment: Yes.. I'll check and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Here's the output I'm getting `{"_id":"56d98dc1c6ca1fb0140d8e05","Birthday":"7-Dec-87","ID":"1","Name":"user1"}
{ '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#',
  title: 'Product',
  type: 'string' }` and Here's the code `app.get('/birthdaylist/:id', function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    db.collection('birthday').findOne({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, function (err, doc) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
        var schema = GenerateSchema.json('Product', JSON.stringify(doc));
        console.log(schema);
        res.json(doc);
    });
});`

Comment: OK I read the instructions.  Try `GenerateSchema.mongoose('Product', doc)`.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. Wll try and let you know.

Comment: `var schema = GenerateSchema.mongoose('Product', JSON.stringify(doc));`
 output is this : `{"_id":"56d98dc1c6ca1fb0140d8e05","Birthday":"7-Dec-87","ID":"1","Name":"user1"}`

Comment: I've did something like this `var schema = GenerateSchema.json('Product', JSON.stringify(doc));
var monschema = GenerateSchema.json('Product', schema);
console.log(monschema);` and output is as follows: `{ '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#',
  title: 'Product',
  type: 'object',
  properties:
   { '$schema': { type: 'string' },
     title: { type: 'string' },
     type: { type: 'string' } } }`

Comment: Now how can I generate html form from above?

Answer (score 4):

Form generation is not a trivial task. You may want to consider using a library for this. Here are a few that might be useful to you:

http://schemaform.io/

https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor/

Also, if you need help generating JSON schema from JSON:

http://jsonschema.net/#/

and of course: http://json-schema.org/

Comment: For this first I need to define schema to generate html form but in my case data is coming from excel (dynamically) which can be anything. So how can I define schema for it. Ex: `[ 
  { dob: '7-Dec-87', ID: '1', Name: 'user1' },
  { dob: '8-Dec-87', ID: '2', Name: 'user2' },
  { dob: '9-Dec-87', ID: '3', Name: 'user3' },
  { dob: '4-Dec-87', ID: '4', Name: 'user4' } 
], [ 
  { dob: '7-Dec-87', ID: '1', Name: 'user1' },
  { dob: '8-Dec-87', ID: '2', Name: 'user2' },
  { dob: '9-Dec-87', ID: '3', Name: 'user3' },
  { dob: '4-Dec-87', ID: '4', Name: 'user4' } 
]`

Comment: You've converted your Excel file to JSON, so all you need to do now is convert your JSON to JSON schema (or create a JSON schema manually). This tool should help you get started: http://jsonschema.net/#/